# How add adsense to flowplayer?

Tags: javascript, adsense

I have next problem, flowplayer have next documentation:

```
<div id="image_text" class="flowplayer functional"></div>

<!-- install the player with ima AdSense configuration -->
<script>
flowplayer("#image_text", {
  // configure the AdSense plugin for this player
  ima: {
    // must be set when testing your installation
    adtest: true,
    // make the Google robots crawl the current page
    description_url: location.href,

    // adverts configuration
    ads: [{
      // mandatory: schedule ad time
      // here: 3 seconds into the video
      time: 3,

      // request an advert of type image or text type
      ad_type: "image_text"
    }]
  },

  splash: true,
  ratio: 5/12,
  rtmp: "rtmp://s3b78u0kbtx79q.cloudfront.net/cfx/st",
  clip: {
    sources: [
      { type: "video/webm",
        src:  "//stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus.webm" },
      { type: "video/mp4",
        src:  "//stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus.mp4" },
      { type: "video/flash", src: "mp4:bauhaus" }
    ]
  }
});
</script>
```

We add empty block for adsense and some script for this block write? But where i need to write adcode? Please help me, how do I add Google ads to flowplayer, sorry for worst english.